# Spray route rejections

Tags: scala, routes, spray

I am building some custom directives with Spray and I find a problem:

When a route is rejected I thought that it was immediately completed with a rejection. However it is not and it tries to complete the inner route. For example, in this code:

```
path("users") {
  post {
    entity(as[User]){
      user =>
        directive_always_reject(){
          println("Hello")
          complete(200, "Hello")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The "hello" is always printed, even if the directive is rejected.

I always thought that when a route is rejected it does not continue to inner routes (or at least is how I understand it)
Did I misunderstand something with Spray or there is a bug somewhere in my code?

Thanks you!

[UPDATE 1]

An implementation of directive_always_reject() could be:

```
def directive_always_reject[T]() : Directive0 = {
  reject(
    new ValidationRejection("Some error")
  )
}
```

[UPDATE 2]

I see that a solution could be put the `println` inside the `complete` function.

```
path("users") {
  post {
    entity(as[User]){
      user =>
        directive_always_reject(){
          complete {
            println("Hello")
            "Hello"
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

However this solution does not apply to me because in my real code I pass the `RequestContext` to another actor who is the one that completes the request.

Comment: I think it depends on *directive_always_reject* directive, could you give an example?

Comment: @sap1ens I updated the question with a simple implementation of _directive_always_reject_

Comment: I'm also having this issue. Curious if you ever found a resolution

Comment: I am no longer working on that project...I don't remember how I solved it. Take look at this link about rejections  http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.3/spray-routing/key-concepts/rejections/) and this one about DSL structure http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.3/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/. Hope this helps!